# Looking for orthodox movies about St. Francis and St. Clare

Tags: history, hagiography, entertainment, francis-of-assisi

There are tons of movies about St. Francis and St. Clare,  is there a complete list of movies that, I don't know, rank by historicity and orthodoxy?   I've seen a few movies about them but can't remember which, I know *The Flowers of St. Francis* is good, but it's not necessarily based on anything particularly historical.

So, what I'd like to see is a complete list, with a relative rating (maybe on a scale of 1-10) for historicity and orthodoxy.  I'm trying to find some movies for a curriculum I'm putting together for my daughter's homeschool.

Comment: Do they have to be in English?

Comment: @ken yeah, at least English subtitles,